# SwiftUI Button: Preserve highlighted state without ugly animation

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a quiz view with buttons per answer. After the user chooses an answer, the respective button should remain highlighted. The problem is that I get an unwanted transition animation, it seems that the following happens

1. User holds button: isPressed = true
2. User taps button: isPressed = false
3. Button action is triggered: answerState == .highlighted

This results in an animation where the button is unhighlighted in step 2 and highlighted again in step 3, which is quite ugly. Do you have any idea how to solve that issue?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct QuizView: View {
    @State var quizQuestion = QuizManager.shared.generateQuestion()
    @State var selectedAnswer: Insignia? = nil
    @State var isSolutionPresented = false
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?

    var body: some View {
        QuizGrid(self.quizQuestion.elements) { quizElement in
            if quizElement.type == .question {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Group name")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        Text(quizElement.insignia.wrappedName)
                            .font(.title)
//                            .font(.system(size: 30.0, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                            //.fontWeight(.heavy)
                            //.lineLimit(2)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .padding(.top, 5)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    self.selectedAnswer = quizElement.insignia
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                        self.presentSolution()
                    }
                }) {
                    Image("Image")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                }
                .buttonStyle(
                    QuizAnswerButtonStyle(answerState: self.answerState(answer: quizElement.insignia))
                )
                .disabled(self.selectedAnswer != nil)
            }
        }
        .gridStyle(
            (horizontalSizeClass == .compact && verticalSizeClass == .regular) ? QuizGridStyle(columns: 2, rows: 2, questionPosition: .top, relativeQuestionSize: CGSize(width:1, height: 0.3)) : QuizGridStyle(columns: 4, rows: 1, questionPosition: .top, relativeQuestionSize: CGSize(width:1, height: 0.3))
        )
    }

    struct QuizAnswerButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
        var answerState: QuizAnswerState

        func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
            ZStack(alignment: .init(horizontal: .center, vertical: .center)) {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .colorMultiply(self.fillColor(answerState: (configuration.isPressed || self.answerState == .highlighted) ? .highlighted : self.answerState))
                configuration.label
            }
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .strokeBorder(Color("quizItemBorderColor").opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .cornerRadius(10)
        }

        func fillColor(answerState: QuizAnswerState) -> Color {
            switch(answerState) {
            case .neutral:
                return Color("quizItemNeutralColor")
            case .highlighted:
                return Color("quizItemHighlightedColor")
            case .correct:
                return Color("quizItemCorrectColor")
            case .incorrect:
                return Color("quizItemIncorrectColor")             
            }
        }
    }

    func answerState(answer: Insignia) -> QuizAnswerState {
        if self.isSolutionPresented {
            if (self.selectedAnswer?.objectID == answer.objectID && answer.objectID == self.quizQuestion.question.objectID) || (self.selectedAnswer?.objectID != answer.objectID && answer.objectID == self.quizQuestion.question.objectID) {
                return .correct
            } else if self.selectedAnswer?.objectID == answer.objectID && answer.objectID != self.quizQuestion.question.objectID {
                return .incorrect
            }else {
                return .neutral
            }
        } else {
            return self.selectedAnswer?.objectID == answer.objectID ? .highlighted : .neutral
        }
    }

    func presentSolution() {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)) {
            self.isSolutionPresented = true
        }
        let delay = self.selectedAnswer?.objectID == self.quizQuestion.question.objectID ? UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "QuizDelayAfterCorrectAnswer") : UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "QuizDelayAfterIncorrectAnswer")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
            self.loadQuestion()
        }
    }

    func loadQuestion() {
        self.isSolutionPresented = false
        self.selectedAnswer = nil
        self.quizQuestion = QuizManager.shared.generateQuestion()
    }
}

public enum QuizAnswerState {
    case neutral
    case highlighted
    case correct
    case incorrect
}
```

For the following demo, I added a scale animation for better visibility of the issue. The first interactions are just pressing the button without actually selecting it. The animation looks good. The last interaction is selecting the button, and there is this strange animation.

[image: demo_transition]

Comment: for suggestion: try add .animation(nil) to your button

Comment: Would you show how do you use this style and demo of *ugly* result, because in my test I do not see anything unexpected?

Comment: @Asperi, I added the full struct code plus a GIF of how it looks like, demoed with a scale animation (same behavior as for the color). The first interactions only show a press interaction and everything looks normal. Then, the subsequent interactions show what goes wrong when the button is actually selected.

Comment: @Mac3n, I tried that, but that also disables the "isPressed animation", which is desirable here.

Comment: It is hard to make this work, too many custom components are absent, but I'm sure that the origin of the issue is in many dependencies (many sources affecting style) - try to make it single-source and you'll fix it easily.

Comment: @Asperi, I made selectedAnswer my only State variable, with all other being static. This does unfortunately not change the behavior. And I don't see a way to further reduce the complexity. "configuration.isPressed" is already given, and I have only one additional variable that controls the state.